# Shrink Height Of List Items In Listview

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am creating a collapsible listview the markup is below. I want to be able to shrink the height of the list items currently I can only fit a few on a mobile screen.

```
<div id="accMain0" data-role="collapsible" data-inset="true" data-collapsed="false">
    <h3>
        Travel
    </h3><div id="myAppsSectionGridTable" data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
        <li><a onclick="selectApproval(&#39;ed5895bc-0f4a-e211-a9ba-0050568e20a1&#39;,&#39;XP%2boFSgWxG0%3d&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;true&#39;,&#39;false&#39;,&#39;false&#39;,&#39;true&#39;)"><img src="Images/travel.png" alt="" class="ui-li-icon" /><h3>
    Victor Chavez
        </h3><p>Try Again NAck12345</p></a></li><li>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `height`?

Comment: Sounds like you need a [JQUery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

Comment: Im not sure how to implement height with jquery mobile? If I force to a height then it wont resize in different mobile devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can override `margin`, `padding` and a `font-size` if you want in a few jQM styles

```css
.ui-li-heading { 
    /*font-size: 16px;*/
    margin: .3em 0; 
}
.ui-li-desc { 
    /*font-size: 12px;*/
    margin: -.5em 0 .3em; 
}

.ui-li .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit, .ui-li-static.ui-li {
     padding-top: .2em; 
     padding-bottom: .2em; 
}
```

**Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/VRdWM/)**